# JQuery sort a list based on initial word before hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list that is generated from database something like this

```
bajaj-4S-champion
bajaj-avenger
audi-a3-diesel
audi-a3-petrol
```

and so on. This is just an example, initials can be any like bajaj, it can be Chevrolet. I want to dynamically sort the list such that all that start with same initial should be in separate div. In this case, bajaj-4S-champion and 
    bajaj-avenger should be separated and Audi should be separated. How to compare the initials before hyphen and separate them out?

Comment: In general, it is best practice to avoid using jQuery for this kind of data manipulation.  This kind of thing can be done in plain JavaScript, and when you do so, you eliminate a dependency.  There are some really (REALLY) useful array functions that you might want to look at, like filter, map, reduce, sort, join, and forEach (in addition to String.split).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the data first and then group it in an object for further processing.

```js
var array = ['bajaj-4S-champion', 'bajaj-avenger', 'audi-a3-diesel', 'audi-a3-petrol'],
    object = {};

array.sort();
array.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = a.split('-')[0];
    object[key] = object[key] || [];
    object[key].push(a);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it